# Why do we need to set packages to scan explicity for H2 datasource configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

**Why do we need to set packages to scan explicitly for H2 datasource configuration ?**
**And, how can I use the same beans created by @Entity here ?**

If I remove the `em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.practice.demo.entity" });` then I get this error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
> resource [com/practice/demo/config/TestPostgresConfig.class]:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No persistence units parsed from
> {classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml}

I have this below configuration for H2 in-memory database :

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;

@Configuration
@Profile("test")
public class TestPostgresConfig {

    
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        /** To keep the content of an in-memory database as long as the virtual machine is alive 
            use jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1 */ 
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:testdb:9090;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1");
        dataSource.setUsername("sa");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        
        return dataSource;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        System.out.println("Configuring the entityManagerFactory");
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.practice.demo.entity" });
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        // Added hbm2ddl properties to create the tables automatically and avoid using DatabaseInitializer.
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        return em;
    }
    
    @Bean
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        System.out.println("Configuring the transactionManager");
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }
    
    
    final Properties additionalProperties() {
        final Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();

        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("spring.jpa.database-platform", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        return hibernateProperties;
    }
}
```

I have the entity class as :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class EmployeeEntity {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name= "emp_id")
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name="gender")
    private String gender;
    
    @Column(name="date_of_birth")
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    
    @Column(name="address")
    private String address;
    
    public EmployeeEntity(CreateEmployeeRequest createEmployeeRequest) {
        this.name = createEmployeeRequest.getName();
        this.gender = createEmployeeRequest.getGender();
        this.dateOfBirth = createEmployeeRequest.getDateOfBirth();
        this.address = createEmployeeRequest.getAddress();
    }

}
```

And the main Application as:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: As you are using Spring Boot why do you have this configuration in the first place?

Comment: Answering part of your question: "Why do we need to set packages to scan" - technically you can scan all classpath, but it may take like 5 seconds even in a simple program.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum, is it not required to have this configuration ? Is there a default/better way to set different datasource?  I have ComponentScan to scan all the entities objects, and this datasource I have configured for in-memory JPA testing.

Comment: Hi @ILyaCyclone, I think I confused readers with the question, let me rephrase it. My question is, Why do I need to set packages to scan explicitly in configuration class when I already have ComponentScan in main spring application class?

Comment: Spring Boot auto configures all of this. Component scan doesn't detect the entities **only** spring components.

Comment: Understood, removing the componentscan from the code as SpringBootApplication annotation takes care of that. But still, how to configure H2 without specifying the entity package ?